# Cannot 'Add and Remove' Maven Project with Websphere 7 on RAD 8.5

Tags: maven, rad, websphere-7

Thank you in advance for your help!

I can access the Admin console in Websphere 7 and install the EAR file successfully for a maven project.

I cannot right click on the Websphere 7 server, In Rad 8.5, and select 'Add and Remove'. When I do that, it doesn't show the maven project. Instead, it shows ' There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server'

Any Ideas for how to get it to show up under 'add and remove'?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [video tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/nfrsblog/entry/using_maven_integration_tools_in_ibm_rational_application_developer_a_two_part_video_series2?lang=en) provided by IBM as

#### 1. [Using Maven Integration Tools in IBM Rational Application Developer, Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2eBTGfB-hM&feature=youtube_gdata)

This presentation introduces Rational Application Developer and WebSphere Application Server developer tools for Eclipse support for Maven Development.

#### 2. [Using Maven Integration Tools in IBM Rational Application Developer, Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpKrF1dHtvM&feature=youtube_gdata)

This presentation introduces Rational Application Developer and WebSphere Application Server developer tools for Eclipse support for Maven Development. Here we cover project conversion, project configuration, defining dependencies, and running on server.

There is also the PDF version as

#### [Rational Application Developer and M2Eclipse: Maven in the development workbench](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/2fad2df2-9c68-4aa3-abba-01e910211998/page/9615e26f-77b4-45d0-a8aa-bfeb64af1f20/attachment/6b1e3c1e-ff32-4468-a646-72f3175eb3ec/media/rad_m2e-nov.pdf)

This paper explores real-world scenarios using Rational® Application Developer and m2eclipse together.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but perhaps still helpfull for those running into this problem. What worked for me?

After a succesfull **build on the command line** I ran **'mvn eclipse:eclipse'** to generate the prefs files for the project to import it smoothly into eclipse/Rad as a **'general project'**. After this the **wtp-migration tool** popped up. I let it run and after correcting some **project facet** issues in the **project properties** I could easily see and add the ear module to my **WAS7 server**.