# Is there a Maven plugin for version 0.12.1.20110112-1712?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, rad

No existing update site is active/up to install the maven plugin version (0.12.1.20110112-1712) for RAD (8.0.4).

A friend of mine already has this version of Maven installed. I tried by copying p2 folder which contains plugin and feature. But doing so, shows the Maven version in the installed software list, but no maven option is available in the RAD.

It will be great if I can find the ACTIVE update url for Maven "0.12.1.20110112-1712".

Comment: Which maven plugin do you want? the `m2e` or `m2e-wtp`?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is only version `1.0` - `1.3` available at the `Eclipse Update Site`.

Comment: Is there any alternate way for this, as my friends already have m2e 0.12 version installed.So, I mean by copying the plugin folder...

Comment: Anyhow the formal `IBM RAD document` for `V8.0.4`,`V8.0.4.1`, `V8.5.0` mentions about version `1.0.100.20110804-1717`. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906938/cannot-add-and-remove-maven-project-with-websphere-7-on-rad-8-5/16909844#16909844)

Comment: If I use the newer version, I get "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" compilation error in POM. ref. link explanation for the same.. <http://java.sg/maven-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration/>    also my team is working using m2e 0.12 version only, so I can't use other versions..  thanks.

Comment: ...Found the site where m2e 0.12 version is visible, but it's update site not working... update site https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e/0.12.1/S/0.12.1.20110112-1712/                                     how to proceed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found the update site for the required version.

update site : http://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e/0.12.1/S/0.12.1.20110112-1712/

Answer Source : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.plugins.m2eclipse.user/7972

The update site were not working with 'https' instead given 'http' and worked for me.