# Setting up M2Eclipse with Eclipse Galilio (3.5)

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to setup M2Eclipse with Eclipse Galilio. But to my surprise, m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e is down from june 2013 and its related sites as well. I searched in the www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse site to find out that they have moved all the archives into the site: repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/forge-sites/m2e/

But, I was unable to download anything from the above site. Please can anyone let me know how to setup maven with Eclipse Galilio?

I did get a m4eclipse plugin setup... but it is not good. It doesn't have the 'import maven projects' feature. It just manages the dependencies of the project.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: Please see [Urgently require Maven plugin for version 0.12.1.20110112-1712](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977556/urgently-require-maven-plugin-for-version-0-12-1-20110112-1712?noredirect=1#comment24594448_16977556)

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlee ... it worked like a charm... just one change which i did is to use Https ... :) Thank you again  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a release newer than Galileo, like Kepler.  Maven support is now provided at http://eclipse.org/m2e/ with http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ as the update site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .... sadly, i am forced to use the specific version as the OSB integration only works fine with the 3.5 version.

Comment: or if you are forced to use eclipse 3.5 to support a legacy weblogic portal application ...