# Deploy Spring Boot project to WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere

I'm trying to deploy my **spring boot project** (made by spring initializr) with maven (but same issue with gradle) on **WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5** but it seems impossible to me.
Every-time I try to add to server from *"Add and Remove"* it says *"There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server"*.
So I tried changing Dynamic Web Module on **Project properties --> project facets** but nothing changed.
Is it possible to deploy on WAS 8.5.5?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar reported issue here: [Cannot 'Add and Remove' Maven Project with Websphere 7 on RAD 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906938/cannot-add-and-remove-maven-project-with-websphere-7-on-rad-8-5).

I completely removed my project from RAD. I then extracted zip file from Spring Initializr to create a Maven project. I used "mvnw eclipse:eclipse" command and it successfully created build. I imported that as a general project to RAD.

I then clicked on project. Clicked on properties. Clicked on project facets. None were available, but it prompted me to create them and I did. From there, I selected Dynamic Web Module facet (and also JAX-RS, but I'm not sure if you'll care about that one). I clicked apply and close.

After this, I was able to add and remove resource to Websphere server. I don't know if this is preferred steps or not. I am learning, just as you are. But, it appeared to work.

I specified Java 8 Jar in Spring Initializr for packaging. Maven version is 3.8.4. Spring Boot 2.6.5 (it was pre-selected for me). I am using RAD 9.7 and Websphere server that is stood up in IDE is version 8.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy spring boot to WebSphere 9 you would  want to choose War packaging and Java 8. The zip file from the spring initializr includes a Help.md file with links to helpful documentation. After you extract the zip file, use File -> Import existing maven project into a new workspace.

Comment: I looked closer at the spring framework v5.3.17 documentation, which is the version currently used by the spring initializr, and I believe WebSphere 8.5.5 is not supported. "As of Spring Framework 5.0, Spring requires the Java EE 7 level (e.g. Servlet 3.1+, JPA 2.1+) as a minimum"